# iPhone Application crashes in "AdHoc" mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, build-process

i got a little application which is working very well with my "debug" configuration on my phone and in simulator.

i created a adhoc provisioning profile, and added a "beta" configuration to it.

trying to launch the application with the ad-hoc configuration crashes my application immediatelly.

the console output is:

```
Running…
Error launching remote program: failed to get the task for process 2434.
Error launching remote program: failed to get the task for process 2434.
The program being debugged is not being run.
The program being debugged is not being run.
```

i also created a dist.plsit, unchecked the get-tast-allow and setted this file in my built settings under code signing.

does anyone have an idea?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple thing. i clicked "built and run" instead of "built".

an ad-hoc version cannot be debugged :D

Comment: I know this was written long ago but I'm commenting to hopefully help others. You absolutely CAN debug in adhoc mode. although it's a PITA.  Use NSLogs to track what's happening like normal. Use the organizer with your phone attached to watch the console... NSLogs go there as "warnings" - track and debug!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes when you change lots of things, especially build configs, xcodebuild doesn't seem to figure out which files are stale and links in old stuff that needs to be rebuilt. Try doing a Clean All or just delete your build directory from the project dir. That seems to solve most of these bizarre-ass unexplainable problems for me.

Comment: i already removed my complete build directory and re-compiled the app. strange

Comment: the strange thing is, it works on my iphone with the ad-hoc profile. but not on other beta tester devices (yes, there unique id's are in this profile). thats horrible :(